# Import a Web Service Client from a WSDL in Java

Tags: java, web-services, apache-commons

Im trying to use a web service.

My project is Java 6, using Jboss 4.3.2.GA.
I've tryied to import the web service using the New-> Web Service Client in Eclipse.
Like this tutorial http://www.craigsprogramming.com/2011/03/tutorial-consume-any-web-service-using.html

But when i try to get the Soap Client in this code:

```
WebServiceEscolaSoapStub service = (WebServiceEscolaSoapStub)new WebServiceEscolaLocator().getWebServiceEscolaSoap();
```

I get the following error.

```
org.apache.commons.discovery.DiscoveryException: Class org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory does not implement org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.ClassUtils.verifyAncestory(ClassUtils.java:180)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.verifyAncestory(SPInterface.java:201)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.SPInterface.newInstance(SPInterface.java:195)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass.newInstance(DiscoverClass.java:579)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:418)
at org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverSingleton.find(DiscoverSingleton.java:378)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory$1.run(LogFactory.java:45)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.getLogFactory(LogFactory.java:41)
at org.apache.axis.components.logger.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:33)
at org.apache.axis.handlers.BasicHandler.<clinit>(BasicHandler.java:43)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.getAxisClient(Service.java:104)
at org.apache.axis.client.Service.<init>(Service.java:113)
at br.com.portalpitagorasdeeducacao.gestaodeusuarios.Service.WebServiceEscolaLocator.<init>(WebServiceEscolaLocator.java:12)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear.

You are mixing two jars slf4j and commons-logging. Get rid of commons-logging.jar file.
On second thought remove all logging for now and just a run webservice client to see if you get an output. Later you can add the logging. This error has nothing to do with webservice error.